# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'retry_rdd' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

local variable 'retry_rdd' referenced before assignment python error

I tried referencing it as a global variable but still it gives the name 
 not defined error.

```
    def send_message(self, df):
        #global retry_rdd
        try:

            results_rdd.cache()
            logger.info("Count of the list in rdd = " + str(results_rdd.count()))

            error_rdd = results_rdd.filter(lambda x: '(numbers_sent,messages_sent)' not in x)
            logger.info(error_rdd.count())

            retry_rdd = error_rdd.mapPartitions(
                lambda part: self.retrySend_msg(part, config, token))
            retry_rdd.cache()

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Error occurred while sending to dest.")
            logger.error(e)

        if retry_rdd and retry_rdd.count() > 0:
            error_archive = '{}/{}/'.format(self.config['error']['process'], self.get_time())

            logger.info("Saving errors to archive: {}".format(error_archive))
            retry_rdd.saveAsTextFile(error_archive)
```

Comment: `retry_rdd = None` at top of the function should work

Comment: ```def send_message(self, df):
        retry_rdd = none
        try:```

something like this?

Comment: yes, did it worked? it should be `None` with capital `N`

Comment: If an exception happens, then the rest of the function should not be executed. Add `return` as the last statement in the `except` block.

Comment: @anuragal
 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rdd'

Comment: @user11307842, this is a different error, please debug your code properly. You are accessing some object with `None` value.